# Proof that the set of all prime numbers is not open

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm having some trouble understating this proof. The objective of the proof is to prove that the set $\mathcal{P}$ of all prime numbers is not open in the euclidean topology:

> We shall now prove that $\mathcal{P}$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The proof goes by contradiction. Assume that it is an open subset, then given any $p_k \in \mathcal{P}$, there exists and open subset $(a,b) \subset \mathcal{P}$ such that $p_k \in (a,b)$. Let $\epsilon = \min(\{p_k-a,b-p_k\})$. By Archimedean property, we have that there exists a positive integer $n \geq 2$ such that $\frac1n \lt \epsilon$. Now we have $p_k \pm \frac1n \in (a,b)$ but $p_k \pm \frac1n \notin \mathcal{P}$. CONTRADICTION. Hence, $\mathcal{P}$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

My main question is about the Archimedean property. Why do they use it here? They state that because of the Archimedean property, $\exists n \geq2:\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$, but because $\lim \frac{1}{n}=0$ (meaning that we can get arbitrarily close to $0$ as we want), isn't that obvious? Is it necessary to use the Archimedean property? And what's the purpose of that $\epsilon$ that they defined?

Comment: This proof is kind of weird. If $r$ is any integer, not just a prime, then $(r-1/2,r+1/2)$ contains exactly one integer: $r$ itself, and no other. Since the prime numbers are integers, that completes the proof. I have no idea why the Archimedean property is involved here.

Comment: It appears that the proofwriter also wanted their proof to address the question "How do we know the interval of real numbers $(r-1/2,r+1/2)$ (or, $(r-\epsilon, r+\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon>0$) contains more real numbers other than $r$?" So this makes it sound like one of those classes where you do real analysis from "first principles" including the construction of the reals as the unique complete ordered field, etc etc w/Archimedean property and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask about the purpose of $\epsilon$. It's purpose is that it gives you a "cushion" for adding something to $p_{k}$ and staying in the interval $(a,b)$. In other words, if I take any number $0<\delta<\epsilon$, then $p_{k}+\delta\in (a,b)$ *by definition of $\epsilon$*.

Now the road to a contradiction is to choose a $\delta>0$ satisfying two things:

1. The first is that you want $\delta<\epsilon$. Like we already discussed, you need this to ensure $p_{k}+\delta\in (a,b)$ so that you know $p_k+\delta\in\mathcal{P}$.
2. The second thing you want is $\delta<1$. Why? Because then $p_k+\delta$ will *not be an integer* and so it can't be in $\mathcal{P}$ (a subset of the integers).

These two things will contradict each other so the main question now is: How do I know there is a real number $\delta>0$ that is both less than $\epsilon$ and less than $1$?

The proof you quote uses the the archimedean property to find such a $\delta$. The archimedian property tells me there is an integer $n$ that is bigger than $1$ and bigger than $1/\epsilon$. So if $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$ then $\delta<1$ and $\delta<\epsilon$. You say that this seems obvious and maybe you're right. But at some point or other one has to explain *why* its obvious that $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ using the way integers are defined.

You're right that the proof comes off a little overdone. For one thing you only need to find one number in $(a,b)$ that is not in $\mathcal{P}$ to get a contradiction. The proof you quote finds two: $p_{k}+\frac{1}{n}$ and $p_{k}-\frac{1}{n}$. In other words, if $\epsilon$ is defined as in the proof and $0<\delta<\epsilon$ then you actually know $p_{k}+\delta\in (a,b)$ and $p_{k}-\delta\in(a,b)$. But this is more than sufficient and in reality you would only need to take $\epsilon=b-{p_k}$ to do run the argument I just described.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$, the natural way of doing it is to use the Archimedian property. Therefore, there is no big difference between those two options. And the numer $\min\{p_k-a,b-a_k\}$ is the distance from $p_k$ to $a$ if $a$ is closer to $p_k$ than $b$ and it is equal to the distance from $p_k$ to $b$ if $b$ is closer to $p_k$ than $a$. So, with this choice of $\varepsilon$, if $|x-p_k|<\varepsilon$, then $x\in(a,b)$ too.